# How to export sql from model in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

is there any possibility to export only tables visible in one diagram to .sql file, not including whole DB structure?

For example I have two projects with very similar DB, but different in few tables and I want to keep structure of both in one .mwb file.

I know I can select tables to export, but I am trying to avoid selecting and deselecting that same tables over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If you like you can file a feature request (http://bugs.mysql.com).